# Post message on a specific session ID

Tags: java, web-services, session, tomcat, named-pipes

I have a situation here .. maybe someone can help me with this.

I'm trying to provide a service where clients can "analyze" a specific URL. So I use a web service in Tomcat to work with the clients. The user accesses the web service webpage, inputs a URL and presses analyze. I now have to receive the URL in the web service, send it to a process that is running on the same server as Tomcat ( I do this through a pipe right now ).
The process adds the URL's in a queue, starts consuming it and analyzes every URL. 
After the processing is done, I want to post a message from this process to the same session ID that sent me that URL ( lets' say I send the session ID through the pipe, together with the URL ).The URL after analyze, has to get to the client that pressed Analyze in the end. 
Will what I want be possible?
I tried to find a solution where I would use only pipe communication between the web service and the local process, but a lot of complications appear when we are taking about multiple users connecting on the same time.

Comment: Why the second process? And why the queue? Just execute the analysis and return the result as the response.

Comment: The analysis is done using c++ code. So I need a second process. I use some libraries that are only available in c++. It's complicated code. I can't do it in java.